# How to use IOC in a plugin framework

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I am going to build a Xamarin Application that is a menu Shell where I can plugin modules.

I am New to IOC, but I want to try to use Unity in this project.

My question is: Where do I put the Unity container? Should it be in an assembly of its own? If I do that, should not this assembly have a reference to all assemblies that has a class that Unity should handle? Or is it a better way?

What about the plugins. Should every plugin have an instance of Unity.

I’m very uncertain on how this could be done, so I would be very grateful for suggestions.

Thore

Answer (score 3):

> Where do I put the Unity container? Should it be in an assembly of its
>   own?

The container should be used and configured solely in your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

> What about the plugins. Should every plugin have an instance of Unity.

In general, there should only be one single instance of your DI container per AppDomain! Only in special cases where you run multiple isolated modules you should have multiple container instances.

Comment: +1. In addition, since plugins are (I assume) libraries, you may want to follow the [guidelines for DI-friendly libraries](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library).